annobin error while building perl modules on Rocky Linux
My problem started from installing perl module with the following command, just as an example:
cpanm --sudo DBI

cc1: fatal error: inaccessible plugin file /modules/langs/gcc/14.1.1/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/14.1.1/plugin/gcc-annobin.so expanded from short plugin name gcc-annobin: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.

I am using compiler of my own, not the system default. This is could be my problem. The system perhaps has its own annobin.  I can download and build annobin. The question, is there a simple instruction as to how to build that into my own gcc plugin directory. This way, when building other people's code such as those DBI, the annobin will in be in the way.
